# Are requests to AWS’ DescribeInstances endpoint free?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm working on a series of tutorials that rely on AWS EC2 instances. I'd like to give users a chance to play around with a limited AWS environment.

`DescribeInstances` is the only endpoint I need for that. However, I'd like to make sure that the possibility of someone spamming that endpoint with thousands/millions of requests won't incur thousand dollar charges on my account.

I tried asking someone at work about it, and they said they've never been charged for Describe requests. However, I'd like some more confirmation on that, which is why I'm asking this question.

NOTE: I've tried asking AWS support, but they are very slow to respond.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This website generally requires that your question be very specific with code examples posted. I recommend drafting up some code that makes use of this and attempting to solve the challenge yourself, then post that for better responses. Make sure that the question will result in an ideal answer (specific helps this). 

General thoughts: Don't allow direct access. Throttle your script per IP. Track requests per IP. Monitor your account activity. Improve over time.

Comment: *"I'd like to give users a chance to play around with a limited AWS environment."*  That strikes me as a very bad idea, at least on initial reading.  The free tier exists for the purpose of allowing users to play around with *their own* AWS account.

Answer (score 0):

The [Amazon EC2 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) has no mention of request-based charges. This differs from other services (for example, Amazon S3) that does specifically mention a request charge.

Therefore, it would seem that there is no per-request charge for Amazon EC2.